# Confusion related to independent and depedent variables in functions of several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $x$ and $y$ are independent variables and the functions $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ are defined as: $f_1(x,y) = x + y$ and $f_2(x,y) = 2(x + y)$, does it make sense to say that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are independent of each other?

I have 2 contradictory thoughts about it:

- They are indeed **independent** because the explicit definitions of both of them are as functions of only the variables $x$ and $y$
- They are **not independent** as one could express one in terms of the other, either $f_1 = f_2\,/\,2$ or $f_2 = 2\,f_1$.

Comment: It is a matter of definitions; I don't know a standard definition of this sort, though.

Comment: If you are computing $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial f_2}$ then they are dependent. If you have a $g(x,y)=f_1(x,y)+f_2(x,y)$ and are computing $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$, then it depends, whether you look at $g$ as $h(a,b)=a+b$ composed with $(a,b)=(f_1,f_2)$, in which case they are independent; or if you see $g$ as $h(a,b)=a+b$ composed with $(a,b)=(a,2f_1)$ and then composed with $(a,x,y)=(f_1,x,y)$, in which case $f_2$ should be seen as dependent. But in the latter case, it doesn't really matter anyway, since you don't need to talk about $f_2$ in the computation.

Comment: At the end, what really matters is not the 'dependent', or 'independent' labels, but the [composition tree](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~emsilvia/math21c/disc2/discset2.html).

Answer (score 0):

If one lets $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$. If $m=1$ then we say that $f$ is a scalar-valued function and if $m > 1$ we say that $f$ is a vector-values function.

If $n=1$ then we say that $f$ is a function of one variable, and if $n > 1$, we say that $f$ is a function of several variables. For
each $x = (x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n) \in D$, the coordinates $x_i$ of $x$ are called the independent variables of $f$.

Take as an example $z=x^2+y^2$. The independent variables are $x, y$ the dependent variable is $z$.